# How to solve code smell: Computed property for output formatting

Tags: ember.js

Hi i have this ember model. The likeMessage computed Property is building a string that i am using in my template. (see below)
This works, but i'm not comfortable having this "view layer code" in my model. What would be a better approach?

```
/**
 * @class
 * @name Entry
 */
James.Entry = Ember.Object.extend(
  /** @lends Entry# */
  {
        likes: [],

        likeMessage: function() {
            var likes = this.get("likes"),
            withNameCount = 0,
            names = [],
            likeCount = likes.length;

            for(;withNameCount < likes.length && withNameCount < 2; withNameCount++) {
                names.push(likes[withNameCount].name);
            }

            if(likeCount == 0) {
                return "Nobody likes this";
            } else if(likeCount == 1) {
                return names[0]+ " likes this";
            } else if(likeCount <= 2) {
                return names.join(" and ")+" like this";
            } else {
                return names.join(", ")+" and "+(likes.length-2)+" others like this";
            }
        }.property("likes")
    }
);
```

My template:

```
Likes:
{{likeMessage}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computed properties that are for presentation belong in the controller layer in Ember. To get easy access to the model, you can use an `Ember.ObjectController` and set the `content` property to the model instance you are showing.

I recently put together a presentation recently about what goes where when architecting an Ember app. Perhaps it could be useful: http://www.lukemelia.com/blog/archives/2012/08/23/architecting-ember-js-apps/

Comment: Thaks, i watched your video and it made sense. So now i am trying to implement it. I have an `EntryController` of type `Ember.ArrayController` that holds a list of entries. Each of them has a list of likes as you can see in the model above. So how do i get those pieces together? I don't quite know how to use an `ObjectController` in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You could move that method pretty much as is to an EntryView and then call **view.likeMessage** in the template.

Without knowing your View classes I cannot be more specific but typically you would have a corresponding view for every model (often two, one "singular" and one "plural" for handling collections or single instances of the model).

Comment: This is is a little better i agree. Any chance i can get that logic into my template?. I've considered writing a handlebar helper that formats the likecount. But i would need that helper only in one template.

Comment: To me it fits well in the View or, as Luke suggests, in the controller. Sorting and pagination is all done in the controller and depending on how you look at this particular property it can be seen as a special presentation of a collection of likes, right? I choose the View simply because it is a gathering and formatting of the likes specific top this view. In another view context you may have room to show more names for example.